# Почему отправляются старые данные?

Tags: python, json, telebot

Часть кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['points'])
def id(message):
    with open('values.json') as json_file:
        values = json.load(json_file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твои баллы {values[str(message.chat.id)][0]}')
```

Если я запущу код когда значение которое он берёт равно 0, то когда я шлю команду /id он мне присылает 0. Если я во время работы кода я изменю значения на 10 в редакторе и сохраню, то когда я присылаю ему команду он мне всё равно присылает 0. Как это исправить, чтобы код всегда присылал свежее значение?

Answer (score 0):

табни строчку

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твои баллы {values[str(message.chat.id)][0]}')
```

у тебя переменная `values` локальная

Comment: Нет, не работает